# Is there any way to reach the Neuwerk island from the German mainland?

Tags: germany, ferries, islands

Recently, I stumbled accross this little island called "Neuwerk" situated northwest from the city of Cuxhaven. It has a firehouse I'd like to see (and visit). Now, I was wondering if it would be possible to get there?
[image]

When I try to look for a navigation to the island, it says there is no possible route to it, so I'm guessing there is no "official" ferry going back and forth, or am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are four hotels on the island, which  you can book online, each of their websites probably has info about how to get there (seeblick-insel-neuwerk.de, husachterndiek.de, inselneuwerk.de, neuwerk-hotel.de).

The light house website (https://www.leuchtturmneuwerk.de/) also has a link to a company that ferries you there (https://www.cassen-eils.de/).

When I try google maps with 'walking' it tells me that you can *walk* there at low tide, but it's about 8 km.

**Don't try that without a professional guide.** (I've taken the liberty to edit this post because that precaution is vital. The tidal flats can change from year to year, even from month to month, and some map on your phone might lead you into a deadly maze. They have to rescue drowning people every year.)

Comment: @AutoDemolisher If you are interested in walking in that area, which is called  "Wattenmeer" in German and [Wadden Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadden_Sea) in English, you can look up "mudflat hiking", which is a popular activity. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudflat_hiking) lists the walk to Neuwerk among the common routes.

Comment: One more comment so stress NOT TO WALK unless guided. Even with good guides, rescues are quite common and without a good guide you are even more likely to get lost, stuck or drowned. Just knowing the tide table is not enough, by a very long way.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, there is a Ferry service between Cuxhaven to Neuwerk Island: https://www.cassen-eils.de/linienverkehr/english-schedule/

> Day guests frequently visit on foot through the mudflats or in one of the horse-drawn carriages, and then return to Cuxhaven on the MS “Flipper”.